# Is the assumption $f \in C^4$ necessary for the composite Simpson's rule to be of order $p=4$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

In my introductory numerics class, we wanted to integrate a function $f \in C[a,b]$ numerically. After developing the Simpson's rule, we proved that if $f \in C^4$ then the composite Simpson's rule has convergence order $p=4$. But then we just kept calling the rule "a 4th order method" without mentioning the $C^4$ condition.

Is the assumption necessary? Is the composite Simpson's rule still a 4th order method for any continuous function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smoothness matters for the order of convergence. A statement that some rule (for integration, differentiation) is of $k$th order should be understood with implicit "if the data is sufficiently regular". Bad data is bad.

For example, try Simpson's rule on $\int_{-1}^1 |x|\,dx$ using $2n$ subintervals, where $n$ is odd. The step size $h$ is $1/n$. The values of $f$ at $k/n$, $k=1,\dots,n-1$, get weight $2$ if $k$ is odd and weight $4$ if $k$ is even. Of course, $f(1)$ gets weight $1$. So, 
$$  \int_{-1}^1 |x|\,dx  \approx \frac{2}{3n}\left( 2 \sum_{1\le k\le n-2,\text{ odd}} \frac{k}{n} + 4\sum_{2\le k\le n-2,\text{ even}} \frac{k}{n} +1 \right)$$
The right hand side is equal to 
$$\frac{2}{3n}\left( 2 \frac{(n-1)^2}{4n} + 4\frac{n^2-1}{4n} +1 \right) = 1-\frac{2}{3n} +\frac{1}{3n^2}$$
So, the error is of order $1/n$ for this function.

Comment: You mean the that the error is in $O(n^{-1})$ which implies it's of the first order, right?

Comment: @LeoSchmidt Yes, that's what I meant... and I think I said what I meant.